# Websockets: <f:websocket> and @ServerEndpoint

Tags: java-websocket, jsf-2.3

I'm currently digging into JSF 2.3 and websockets.

The use of `<f:websocket>` within xhtml pages and the definition of web socket endpoints using `@ServerEndpoint` is clear to me.

But is there any way to combine those two to get `<f:websocket>` to connect to an existing annotated ServerEndpoint?

Haven't found any useful info about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But is there any way to combine those two to get `<f:websocket>` to connect to an existing annotated `ServerEndpoint`?*

No.

The `<f:websocket>` only listens to its own autoregistered `ServerEndpoint`.

Whatever problem you thought to solve this way has to be solved differently.